# flutter app not lunching on the virtual device

Tags: flutter, android-virtual-device, connection-timeout

I tried proxy , vpn
but the base flutter example app not running on avd!
it works fine with lunching on the chrome.
my internet works fine , and I can ping my host.
flutter doctor output returns no error .

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
    main.dart:1
    Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:174)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:183)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:531)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:636)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:266)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:380)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1242)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1128)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2902)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2811)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1927)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1589)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did u define minSdk, targetSdk & compileSdk versions in app/build.gradle ... ?

Comment: yes , that wasnt the p

Answer (score 0):

“The problem was a filtering issue! I solved it by downloading .gradle 7.5 manually and placing it at C:/Users/“myuser”/.gradle. After some waiting, downloading, and erroring, it finally worked! Remember, if you’re having a build issue, you have to solve the Gradle issue.”